# RoR 3 Limiting users to 2 posts per day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, limit

I am looking for away to limit my users from posting more than twice per day and have no more than 5 posts per week. I have a users and posts model/controller.

I have been looking at these questions but they are not quite what I am looking for.

[Rails 3.1 limit user created objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863618/rails-3-1-limit-user-created-objects)

[How do I validate a time in Rails? Limiting a user to post once a day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467638/how-do-i-validate-a-time-in-rails-limiting-a-user-to-post-once-a-day)

Error @ 20:44 13/03/2012 with the code from KandadaBoggu

```
NoMethodError in PostsController#create

undefined method `beginnning_of_day' for 2012-03-13 20:36:11 +0000:Time
```

Comment: looks like "Rails 3.1 limit user created objects" answers your question perfectly.  What is different about what you're asking?

Comment: Can you share some code that you have tried already?

Comment: I have tried that one and it only lets me have 5 posts in total. How would I limit the posts per day and week, instead of just a total?

Comment: I have just combined the code from both links, one block below the other. But it is not what I am looking for.

Comment: you have one extra `n` letter in `beginnning_of_day`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
class User
  has_many :posts do

    def today
      where(:created_at => (Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now))
    end

    def this_week
      where(:created_at => (Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week..Time.zone.now))
    end
  end    
end


class Post
  belongs_to :user

  validate :user_quota, :on => :create  

private 
  def user_quota
   if user.posts.today.count >= 2
     errors.add(:base, "Exceeds daily limit")
   elsif user.posts.this_week.count >= 5
     errors.add(:base, "Exceeds weekly limit")
   end
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks KandadaBoggu. I have added your code and restarted the rails server and now when I'm posting I get the error posted above

Comment: There was a typo in my answer. Try now.

Comment: Thanks KandadaBoggu, this time I am getting this error   "undefined method `Time' for 2012-03-13 21:19:00 +0000:Time"

Comment: While I fixed the typo, I introduced a copy+paste error. Code should work now. PS: You should be able to fix such simple syntax errors by yourself.

Comment: Thanks KandadaBoggu its working. I should have spotted the typo too "nnn" Its one of those days today..